# How possible to delete div with subdivs using regex yahoo pipes?

Tags: html, pipe, yahoo

I have such construction as:

```
<div class="formula_full">

    <div class="f_ltop"></div>
    <div class="f_rtop"></div>
       <div class="f_box"> 
          <img src="*****" alt="">
            <div class="f_box_info">5% Rogue</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which expression I need to use in yahoo pipes regex, to delete all div class"formula_full" with subdiv.
I try to use `<div class="formula_full"[^>]*>(.*?)</div>` , but it delete only partly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pipes regex doesn't understand tags and subtags... So while the regex below will work fine with code text you have mentioned above, if there is any other closing DIV tag below it, this will fail

regex:
<div class="formula_full"(.*)</div>